# Finding Dynamically created TextViews by tag in Adapter getView() method

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-adapter

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

        PlannerMonth m = getItem(position);
        ArrayList<PlannerMonthDebt> debts = new ArrayList<PlannerMonthDebt>();
        debts = m.debtList;

        int debtSize = debts.size();

        if (rowView == null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_planner_month, null, true);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlannerMonth);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) 

            holder.ll = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rlInnerDebtHolder);

            for (int i = 0; i < debtSize; i++) {
                View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_debt_row, null);

                TextView tvName = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.tvInnerDebtName);
                tvName.setTag(String.valueOf("tvName" + i));
                TextView tvPayment = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.tvInnerDebtPayment);
                tvPayment.setTag(String.valueOf("tvPayment" + i));
                TextView tvDebt = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.tvInnerDebtBalance);
                tvDebt.setTag(String.valueOf("tvDebt" + i));
                TextView tvBalance = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.tvInnerDebtFee);
                tvBalance.setTag(String.valueOf("tvBalance" + i));

                holder.ll.addView(custom);
            }
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }


        String month = m.date;
        String debtToal = m.debtTotal;
        String intTotal = m.intTotal;

        holder.tv1.setText(month);
        holder.tv2.setText(debtToal);
        // now inner debts

        int size = 0;
        for (PlannerMonthDebt d : debts) {

            TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf("tvName" + size));
            tvName.setText(d.name);

            TextView tvPayment = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf("tvPayment" + size));
            tvPayment.setText(d.payment);

            TextView tvDebt = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf("tvDebt" + size));
            tvDebt.setText(d.balance);

            TextView tvBalance = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf("tvBalance" + size));
            tvBalance.setText(d.fees);

            size++;       
        }   

        return rowView;
    }
```

Here is the row I am trying to dynamically add:

`inner_debt_row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInnerDebtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInnerDebtFee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInnerDebtPayment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInnerDebtBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a LinearLayout (`holder.ll`) where I add an X number of custom rows (based on the `inner_debt_row` layout pasted above).

I know how to show the rows, but I am having trouble using `setTag()` to find and retrieve them so I can put values to them (via `setText()`.

For the `tag`, I basically use a same name for each `TextView`, but ALSO add a unique position to the name.  I use the position (or size) to keep each of the dynamically added text fields unique for searching.

In my `LogCat`, I get a `NullPointer` on this line:

`TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf("tvName" + size));`

This is the first encounter with assigning a value to a dynamic `TextView` so I assume they all can not be found.

How can I locate the correct TextView instance whit by `tag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `findViewWithTag()` code looks correct. Did you check that `convertView` isn't null?

`convertView` will be null when creating a new row (i.e. not reusing a previous one), but you are assigning `rowView` only, and not `convertView`.

Comment: That was exactly it.  A typo.  Should have used `rowView.findViewWithTag()` instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have different `debtSize` in each position. When `convertView != null` and have less `debtSize` you have `NullPointer`'s, when more - you have empty textviews.